# Using mutable objects as keys in HashMaps

Tags: java, hashmap, graph-algorithm, hashset

I have a digraph data structure which uses list representation(`HashMap<Vertex, ArrayList<Vertex>>` ); source vertex as the key and an ArrayList of destination vertices as the value. A depth first search and dfs loop are used to traverse the graph to find the execution order of the vertices.

The execution order is set as a label of a Vertex object by `setLabel(int i)` and only the `String name` field is used to generate `hashcode`.

My problem is that after `dfs` is completed and when I iterate through the keys of the HashMap [`graph.keySet()`] , there are **still few Vertices** which are not labeled, But when I iterate though the explored set which is a`HashSet<Vertex>`, all the possible vertices are labeled(Accurately).

What could possibly be happening here? (I can only use the HashMap to retrieve the labels of the vertices)

Note: I believe this is relevant to using mutable objects as keys in HashMaps. If not please correct me.

```
 /**
 * Recursive depth-first search     
 * @param graph HashMap<Vertex,ArrayList> (list representation)
 * @param start starting Vertex
 */
public void dfsR(HashMap<Vertex, ArrayList<Vertex>> graph, Vertex start) {
    this.explored.add(start); //a HashSet<Vertex>        

    ArrayList<Vertex> list = graph.get(start);
    if (list != null) {
        for (Vertex v : list) {
            if (!this.explored.contains(v)) {
                this.dfsR(graph, v);
            }
        }
    }
    /* First pass-Execution order */
    if (!this.secondPass) {
        start.setLabel(++this.label);
    }
}

 /**
 * Run DFS on every vertex of the Graph      
 * @param graph HashMap<Vertex,ArrayList<Vertex>> (list representation)
 */
private void dfsLoop(HashMap<Vertex, ArrayList> graph) {
    this.secondPass = false;
    this.explored.clear();        
    this.label = 0;
    for (Vertex vertex : graph.keySet()) {
        if (!this.explored.contains(vertex)) {
            this.dfsR(graph, vertex); /* Recursive dfs */                                
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Vertex {

private final String name;
private int label;    

public Vertex(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.label = -1;
}

public Vertex(Integer name) {
    this.name = String.valueOf(name);
    this.label = -1;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * Value(Label) obtained from Topological Ordering  
 * @param label integer value of the relevant position
 */
public void setLabel(int label){
    this.label = label;
}

/** 
 * @return the Label obtained from the Topological ordering
 */
public int getLabel(){
    return this.label ;
}    

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(o == null){
        return false;
    }
    if (o instanceof Vertex) {
        Vertex v = (Vertex) o;
        return this.name.equals(v.getName());
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;       
    hash = 89 * hash + this.name.hashCode();
    return hash;
}}
```

Comment: _Note: I believe this is relevant to using mutable objects as keys in HashMaps._ That sounds like a reasonable guess. Have you tried correcting this?

Comment: Note: You should probably be using `HashMap<Vertex, ArrayList<Vertex>>` instead.

Comment: Eugh rawtypes. Please please never use them.

Comment: You only use the `name` in `hashCode` and `equals` - this is `final` so the `HashMap` should be happy.

Comment: @Keppil Even though the Vertex object is mutable setting label doesn't change the hashCode. So I believe it's valid key.

Comment: @kuz: So then you don't believe that using mutable objects is relevant to your problem? I am confused.

Comment: @arshajii Nope. It doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @kuz I never said it would. It's just better practice to not use raw types.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is almost certainly related to the management of the `secondPass` variable, as that is what controls whether or not to set the label:

```
if (!this.secondPass) {
    start.setLabel(++this.label);
}
```

The code you provided does not show where this would be set to true.

Comment: No. I can guarantee that it does not change during the execution of the dfs. Above code is a part of the Kosaraju's 2-pass algorithm for computing SCCs and this.secondPass indicates that it's the secondPass and nothing more. Thanks anyways.